# redirect a process started with execv to /dev/null

Tags: c++, linux, fork, stdout

I have a program that `forks()`, and the child process is replaced by another process, say A, that is ran through invoking `execv(A)`.

How do I redirect process `A`'s output to `/dev/null`??

I've so far tried :
(The handle error parts are taken care of, and no error occurs)

```
    pid = fork();
    //check for errors
    if (pid<0){
                  //handle error
    }
    //the child process runs here
    if (pid==0){
        fd = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
        if(fd < 0){
                        //hadnle error
        }
        if ( dup2( fd, 1 )  != 1 ) {
                         //handle error 
        }
        if (execv(lgulppath.c_str(),args)<0){
            //handle error
        }
    }
```

However, that, understandably doesn't work , since it redirects the child process's output to `/dev/null` and not process `A`'s, later to replace the child, output.

Any ideas?
(I don't have the code of `A`'s process)

Thanks

Comment: Your code looks correct. Where do you get an error? Why do you say "this understandably doesn't work"?

Comment: @OlafDietsche, notice that the open and dup2 are invoked before execv is, when open and dup2 are invoked, they redirect the child's process's output to /dev/null.However, when execv is invoked it replaces the child process, and process A's(the one that replaced the child process) will now outputs to stdout and not /dev/null

Comment: @user1432779 `execv` replaces the executable image.  It does _not_ change any open files.  The `dup2` sets standard out to `/dev/null`, and this will not be changed by the `execv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility could be, that process A writes to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

Then you must `dup2(fd, 2)` instead.

If process A writes to `stdout` *and* `stderr`, you must `dup2()` both:

```
if (dup2(fd, 1) < 0) {
    // error handling
}

if (dup2(fd, 2) < 0) {
    // error handling
}
```

Comment: Standard out and standard error have two different file descriptors: 1 and 2.  If process A writes to both, you have to redirect both (using two `dup2`).  (Also, it's generally considered more politically correct to use `STDOUT_FILENO` and `STDERR_FILENO`, rather than `1` and `2`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze and Olaf, Ok I read about dup2 and yeah 2 is stderr fd. Thanks :-)

Comment: @user1432779 Look at the modified answer.

Comment: However, does it cancel what I said above? wouldn't that call redirect the child's output rather than the one called by execv's output?

Comment: @user1432779 It redirects the child's output. But when you `execv(A)`, process A "inherits" the redirection.

Comment: Thanks :-)
One more short question. what if I want to redirect it to /var/log/syslog instead. Do you know if it's possible to open and write to it as a simple file?

Comment: @user1432779 `/var/log/syslog` is a simple file. But it is written to by the `syslog` process, which hears on a socket file and/or UDP port. So this is a bit more complex. If syslog hears on a socket, you could try opening that, instead of `/dev/null`. But I've never tried and don't know if this works really.

Comment: @user1432779 It is a simple file, but normally, only root should have write access to it.  You also don't want to write to it directly, since it has a special format.  What you should do in this case is to write a simple filter, which reads from standard in, and creates a syslog entry for each line it reads, and then set standard error on the child so that it pipes to this filter.